# unknown property 'dependency' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler

Tags: android, twitterkit

I'm trying to clone this [twitter kit repository](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-android), and want to open the sample app in android studio. Then I get this gradle sync error:

```
Error(3,0) Could not get unknown property 'dependency' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

the gradle file with this error:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath dependency.spoonGradlePlugin
    }
}

//Load API Key information in from property file
Properties props = new Properties()
try {
    props.load(file('twitter.properties').newDataInputStream())
} catch (Exception ex) {
   // throw new GradleException("Missing twitter.properties, check the twitter.properties.sample file.");
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'spoon'

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app.twitter"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.targetSdkVersion
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.example.app.SpoonInstrumentationTestRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            resValue "string", "com.twitter.sdk.android.CONSUMER_KEY", "\"${props.getProperty("twitterConsumerKey")}\""
            resValue "string", "com.twitter.sdk.android.CONSUMER_SECRET", "\"${props.getProperty("twitterConsumerSecret")}\""
            resValue "bool", "com.twitter.sdk.android.TRACE_ENABLED", "true"
            resValue "bool", "com.twitter.sdk.android.COLLECT_IDENTIFIERS_ENABLED", "true"
            buildConfigField "String", "MOPUB_AD_UNIT_ID", "\"${props.getProperty("mopubAdUnitId")}\""
        }
        release {
            resValue "string", "com.twitter.sdk.android.CONSUMER_KEY", "\"${props.getProperty("twitterConsumerKey")}\""
            resValue "string", "com.twitter.sdk.android.CONSUMER_SECRET", "\"${props.getProperty("twitterConsumerSecret")}\""
            resValue "bool", "com.twitter.sdk.android.TRACE_ENABLED", "false"
            resValue "bool", "com.twitter.sdk.android.COLLECT_IDENTIFIERS_ENABLED", "true"
            buildConfigField "String", "MOPUB_AD_UNIT_ID", "\"${props.getProperty("mopubAdUnitId")}\""
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }

    spoon {
        if (project.hasProperty('spoonClassName')) {
            className = project.spoonClassName
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        warningsAsErrors true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility rootProject.sourceCompatibilityVersion
        targetCompatibility rootProject.targetCompatibilityVersion
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':twitter')
    compile project(':twitter-mopub')
    compile dependency.appCompat
    compile dependency.design
    compile dependency.okHttpInterceptor

    debugCompile dependency.leakCanary
    releaseCompile dependency.leakCanaryNoOp

    androidTestCompile dependency.spoon
    androidTestCompile dependency.espresso
    androidTestCompile dependency.androidTestingSupport
}
```

I find the dependencies format looks ok. How can I remove this error and run the sample app?